# Laravel Search engine using whereIN

Tags: laravel, where-clause

How Do I use the whereIn clause for a search engine that I am trying to create. I have two inputs one for where the user types in what they are looking for and the other for the city,state or zip code.When I do search for what I'm looking for and the city it shows results,when I look for the state it shows results and when I look for the zip code it shows results, but when I type the city and state it doesn't show results. Can someone help me with this Please? This is like my fourth time that I posted on Stack overflow and still nothing seems to be functioning as I expected. Here is my code

```
     $userinput=$request->input('mywhat');

    $userinputt=$request->input('mywhere');

    $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $userinput));

    $strr = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $userinputt));


    $this->validate($request,array(
       $strr=>'nullable',
    ));

    $pro=Profile::Where('what','Like','%'.$str.'%')->Where(function ($query) use($strr, $userinputt) {
    $query->Where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$strr.'%');

})->orWhere('what','Like','%'.$str.'%')->Where(function ($query) use($strr, $userinputt) {
    $query->Where('state', 'LIKE', '%'.$strr.'%');

})->orWhere('what','Like','%'.$str.'%')->Where(function ($query) use($strr, $userinputt) {
    $query->Where('zipcode', 'LIKE', '%'.$strr.'%');
```

// })->orWhere('what','Like','%'.$str.'%')->Where(function ($query) use($strr, $userinputt) {
     //   $query->Where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$strr.'%');

```
})->orWhere('what','Like','%'.$str.'%')
   ->Where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$strr.'%')
   ->Where( function ($query) use ($strr,$userinputt) {
        $query->Where('state',  'LIKE', '%'.$strr.'%');
        $query->orWhere('zipcode', 'LIKE', '%'.$strr.'%');
   })->inRandomOrder()->paginate(5);

    return view('layouts.reveal')->with('pro',$pro);
```

Comment: Fourth time posting the same question might be an indicator that the problem isn't where you think it is...

Comment: Can you please help me I am like really losing it! I'm trying to search for the city and state but its not allowing me to do that I just really don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm going to update my code and show you what I did.

Comment: I edited it. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: ok I will try thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

See where this gets you (you'll need to change the Model and variables to fit your code, of course):

```
$query = Model::where('search', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
    ->when($city, function ($query) use ($city) {
        return $query->whereCity($city);
    })
    ->when($state, function ($query) use ($state) {
        return $query->whereState($state);
    })
    ->when($zip, function ($query) use ($zip) {
        return $query->whereZip($zip);
    })
    ->get();
```